# Hook or rules event to identify payment failure in Drupal commerce

Tags: 7, hooks, rules, commerce

Is there any hook or rules event that will help to catch the payment failure in Drupal Commerce?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct hook or event, but essential to payment transactions in Drupal Commerce is that they should be created for every *attempted* transaction, not just complete ones. This means when a payment fails, a payment transaction will still be created for your order. Thus you can hook into the payment transaction creation process (or use Rules on the related event) to look for failed transactions based on the transaction status.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `hook_commerce_payment_transaction_status_info()`

Here is a [link](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/hook_commerce_payment_transaction_status_info/DC) to the api and [link](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/payment-info-hooks) to documentation,

Comment: It just defines the transaction statuses. Not a hook to catch any event.

Comment: Can you not check if the payment status is Failure, and if it is do whatever you would like